# Truncation of web socket chunk while uploading a file

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, playframework, websocket

I have tried searching for this strange issue I am facing but could not find anything on web.
Following is what I am trying to do.

Upload File from User browser to Play server running on some different environment

Following is the issue I am facing.

The chunk is getting truncated before reaching to Play server

Observations:

- Chunk is created at client side properly from java script and `websocket.send()` is passing proper chunk to Play.
- On Play server, the chunk is coming as a `String` event object which is truncated.
- Very strange thing about this problem is This is happening only from some machines/networks, for all others it is working fine
- When tried with different chunk size, it has been observed that for smaller chunks many of initial chunks gets received properly and later one fails
- We have tried bypassing Firewalls and Proxies as well on some network to check what happens if there are no such restrictions, but it is still failing

Please give your inputs which can help me debug this and fix this. Any additional things you want I can provide, not pasting code as it is working on majority of machines and networks but failing on a few, so it does not seem to be a code issue

PS. This question can have many answers based on people's views, to all SO users, I just need help on what could be the thing which can go wrong, so please do not flag this as inappropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, the issue was with latest update of google chrome. I downloaded the chrome from [here](http://www.alltypehacks.net/2013/07/download-new-full-google-chrome.html) (Version 37) and it started working fine.

I came to know after a period of time that this issue was because of the implementation changes in chrome V38 for multiple frames for single message, initially it was getting transferred in a single frame so ultimately the implementation from your server side also need to be changed in order to handling the same.

I was using older version of Play framework which wasn't having this multiple frame handling implementation so it was breaking.

After updating Play to 2.2.3 it started working properly as they have implemented multiframe handling in that version. Some useful links below

[Issue With Latest Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226931#c38)

[Play Changelog](https://www.playframework.com/changelog)

[Changes for Continuation frame handling for WebSockets in Play 2.2.3](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2683)